# is it for mysql 8.0.28 or is it a multisite wordpress bug in 5.9

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-mu

```
    cusomizedprefixwp_1_posts: Table 'cusomizedDB.cusomizedprefixwp_1_posts' doesn't exist
cusomizedprefixwp_1_comments: Table 'cusomizedDB.cusomizedprefixwp_1_comments' doesn't exist
cusomizedprefixwp_1_links: Table 'cusomizedDB.cusomizedprefixwp_1_links' doesn't exist
cusomizedprefixwp_1_options: Table 'cusomizedDB.cusomizedprefixwp_1_options' doesn't exist
cusomizedprefixwp_1_postmeta: Table 'cusomizedDB.cusomizedprefixwp_1_postmeta' doesn't exist
cusomizedprefixwp_1_terms: Table 'cusomizedDB.cusomizedprefixwp_1_terms' doesn't exist
cusomizedprefixwp_1_term_taxonomy: Table 'cusomizedDB.cusomizedprefixwp_1_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist
cusomizedprefixwp_1_term_relationships: Table 'cusomizedDB.cusomizedprefixwp_1_term_relationships' doesn't exist
cusomizedprefixwp_1_termmeta: Table 'cusomizedDB.cusomizedprefixwp_1_termmeta' doesn't exist
cusomizedprefixwp_1_commentmeta: Table 'cusomizedDB.cusomizedprefixwp_1_commentmeta' doesn't exist
```

it asked me to repair the table with `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` but repair and optimizations failed.
if you have already encountered this issue or if you have already know the fixes let me know, what did I miss actually? is it for mysql 8.0.28 or is it a multisite wordpress bug in 5.9 both are new released.

thx

Comment: Have you changed the WordPress database table prefix?

Comment: of course, that is how we deal with it always.  for multisite it requires * (wildcard ) in subdomains and most likely Cloudflare will not manage it within the proxy. that is the problem. they will keep it DNS only. it is basically the firewall issue on Oracle Linux 8 or RHEL 8. table name can be prefixed with anything but max table name's length in MySQL 64 characters. this is how is it.

Comment: Subdomains are not related to database table prefix. The error message shows really odd table prefix for the WP table names, so this is why I am asking.

Comment: the error message is odd due to the reason the OS is not ubuntu. it's related to SELinux in rhel 8. x and oracle Linux 8. my OS is Oracle Linux 8.

Comment: The error message is from MySQL, and there is nothing related to operating system in it.

Comment: MySQL supports 64 characters. this is how is it and those tables' names' length was not exceeding that length. BTW: I thought the same way as you think but I found that `php-fpm`  processes are not having enough access due to `SELINUX`'  it was within `/var/log/audit.log` and after that `grep php-fpm /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -a` and `grep php-fpm /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -a -M apache_php_fpm` and during database table creation the PHP is firing ultimately from WordPress installation. but if you have a better solution please share.